# PHP not loading module as user

Tags: php, mysql, drush

I have a problem where `drush` isn't able to connect to my drupal site with mysql. I think it's due to a module loading issue. For example, as root, I check if pdo_mysql is loaded like this:

```
# php -m|grep mysql
mysql
mysqli
pdo_mysql
# php -m|wc -l
55
# which php
/usr/bin/php
# php -i|grep conf
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ldap.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

But when I run this command as my user, I don't see any mysql modules:

```
$ php -m|grep mysql
$ php -m|wc -l
48
$ which php
/usr/bin/php
$ php -i|grep conf
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
```

Why is this? And how do I get these modules to be loaded in php-cli as my user?

I'm using php 5.3.10 (old I know, but it's for compatibility with our production servers) on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: `php -i` to see what config files are being loaded. I suspect it's a file permission problem on reading a php.ini or an included ini file.

Comment: @Ghedipunk i've included the output of `php -i|grep conf`. All the relevant directories/files are world readable and executable.

Comment: Figured it out: I had to do `chmod a+x /etc/php5`. Thanks @Ghedipunk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by making `/etc/php5` executable: `chmod a+x /etc/php5`.